# How to keep the value of a dropdown selected after post (razor)

Tags: sql, razor, drop-down-menu, webmatrix, selected

I have this dropdown in my form and it shows a list of names called from a database. Whenever I select one and submit the form the page refreshes to show the results and the selected value goes back to blank. Is there a way to keep the selected value after I post the form?

```
    <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_22">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_22" for="input_22"> ADMIN </label>
    <div id="cid_22" class="form-input-wide">       
    <select name="formAssigned_To">
    <option></option>  
    @foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Admins")){    
    <option value="@row.Name">@row.Name</option>
    }
      </select>
      </div>
      </li>
```

I have this other dropdown in the same form and this one is static so its not being called from a database and the selected value stays. However, I cannot do the same with the first dropdown, any ideas as to why?

```
   <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_22">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_22" for="input_22"> Status </label>
        <div id="cid_22" class="form-input-wide">
          <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:75px" id="input_22" name="formCase_Status">
            <option selected="@(Request["formCase_Status"])"></option> 
            <option selected="@(Request["formCase_Status"] == "In Progress")" value="In Progress"> In Progress </option>
            <option selected="@(Request["formCase_Status"] == "Pending")" value="Pending"> Pending </option>
            <option selected="@(Request["formCase_Status"] == "Closed")" value="Closed"> Closed </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my question:

```
<select class="form-dropdown" style="width:130px" id="formAssigned_To" name="formAssigned_To"> 
 <option selected =""></option>
 <option selected="@(Request["formAssigned_To"] == "Not Assigned")" value="Not Assigned">Not Assigned</option>
@{foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Admins")){    
 <option selected="@(Request["formAssigned_To"] == row.Name)" value="@row.Name">@row.Name</option>
  }
  }
</select>
```

Nothing other than this worked for me, I hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

On post I save the values back to the database and then I use JQuery to select the appropriate one. This is handy because I use the same screen for edit mode and add mode and when in edit mode it chooses the default one saved in the database. If you want to know how to get values into and out of the database here is a great tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials

And here is a my JQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('[name="programslist"]').val("@programid");
 </script>
```

Here is my  HTML to populate the list:

```
 <label for="programslist">Division:Program</label>
    <select name="programslist" id="programslist">
      @foreach(var row in programsListData)
      {
         <option value="@row.id">@row.Name</option>
      }
      </select>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The @programid is the c# variable where I store the id value from teh database. The tutorial will show you how to store and retrieve that value from the database.

Comment: would you mind sending me the exact link please? I tried the link and it shows many other tutorials, do you remember the name of it?

Comment: Sure thing Alexandra: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data